# Query optimisation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-server-2014

The following is taking a long time to get executed. Considering each table has close to 50 million to 100 million rows, is there anything that I can do from the query side to get it optimized.It is a source table and involves huge data movements (insertion ranging in millions) every hour and is better off without indexes.I don't have the required access to get an execution plan from this server.

```
 DECLARE @var INT

 SELECT TOP 1 @var = s_type
 FROM s_shot
 WHERE s_type < 10000
 ORDER BY s_type DESC;

 WITH cte AS
 (
     SELECT 
         sps_id,
         SUM(xin) xin,
         SUM(xout) xout
     FROM 
         s_lock
     GROUP BY 
         sps_id
)
SELECT 
    A.[s_id], a.acc_id,
    B.[o_type],
    B.[o_id], B.[sec_id], B.[c_id],
    B.[style_type_id], [s_type],
    A.[end_date],
    B.[mv], 
    b.xin + ISNULL(c.xin, 0) [xin],
    b.xout + ISNULL(c.[xout], 0) xout,
    b.accr_in + b.accr_inter [acc],
    b.accr_in, b.accr_inter, 
    b.units
FROM 
    s_shot a WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    s_pos3 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.s_id = b.s_id
JOIN 
    cte c ON b.sps_id = c.sps_id
WHERE 
    b.is_sl = 1
    AND a.end_date > DATEADD(mm, -24, GETDATE())  -- 24 months
```

As you can see, I want to fetch the data of last 24 months. Is there any optimization that is possible in this query so as to bring down its execution time to manageable levels.

The create table scripts are provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[s_shot]
(
    [s_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [acc_id] [int] NULL,
    [s_type] [int] NULL,
    [end_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [recon] [tinyint] NULL,
    [is_pers] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_s_shot_1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [s_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[s_lock]
(
    [sps_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [units] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [accr_in] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [xin] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [xout] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [lock_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [accr_inter] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [mv] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_s_lock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [sps_id] ASC,
    [lock_date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[s_pos3]
(
    [sps_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [s_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [o_type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [o_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [s_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [c_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [s_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [units] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [accr_income] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [distr] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [mv] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [perf_stat] [smallint] NULL,
    [is_slv] [bit] NULL,
    [accr_inter] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [perf_mtd] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
    [xin] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [xout] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [a_s_type_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_s_pos3] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [sps_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Updated indexing details

Comment: Without seeing the execution plan, I would try to split the "cte" from the main query and save the results in a temp table (let's say into #cte), then join the *#cte* temp table in the main query. This **might** give you some improvement (to what degree, I don't know) but I assume the cardinality of the aggregate query is small. You can also create indexes on this *#cte* table, so you might get some speed improvements there too.

Comment: Although you mention the necessary indexes exist, I suggest you post the `CREATE TABLE` DDL with indexes if you need help without the execution plan. Index details (clustered/nonclustered, unique/nonunique, included columns) are important.

Comment: You're being asked to do a job (optimize a query) without being given access to the tools necessary to do it (execution plan). That's a people problem and the problem you *ought* to be trying to solve.

Comment: What does "All necessary indexing is provided" mean? We don't even have the primary key here let alone indexes.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the create table scripts. Does that help? @DanGuzman,  Damien_The_Unbeliever and Nick.McDermaid  ?

Comment: Executionplan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ please. And no, we don't even LOOK at table definition scripts that you paste as PHOTO because you can not be bothered to put them in as text.

Comment: "All necessary indexing is provided", no, they don't as can be seen from your screenshot

Comment: @TomTom I am not given access to view the execution plan. I have taken down the image and added the text.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Yeah I see it now. Those are the source tables and a huge of volume of date is added every hour. So I am told that it is better off without indexes. I am editing that part out.

Comment: Post the DDL as code rather than as an image. It looks like an index on `s_shot(end_date)` might help, especially if you have a lot of older data.

Comment: @DanGuzman i have added it as code and creating index is out of question, I guess as huge amount of data gets inserted every hour.

Comment: If you donÄt have the execution plan access, refuse and tuning job. Period. This is  guessing without the tools to do the job.

Comment: @AsRa, since your tables have only 500M rows and multiple years of history, it seems your hourly insert rate is thousands, not millions. If the date value is incremental, I would not expect the index to significantly impact insert performance. I say this from experience having worked with much larger tables (10s of billions of rows) and much higher insert rates (millions per hour). The performance benefit for the select query might justify the index cost but it's tough to say without the plan.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @marc_s I changed it intentionally as i am not at liberty to share our company table names on online forums.

Comment: OK - but even if your change the table names - you could pick **more intuitive** and more useful table aliases (not just `a`, `b` etc.).....

Comment: @marc_s I will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: I would use MAX in your first variable assignment instead top 1 with an order by. Ordering is very expensive and you only need the largest value that is < 1000. Also, if you care about accuracy get rid of those nolock hints. They are not a magic go fast button. There is some serious baggage with that hint. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/